# Polynomial Multiplication in Galois Field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Compute $(x^4+x^3)*(x^3+x^2+1)$ in the field $GF(2^5)$ generated by $x^5+x^2+1$.

I understand that we wish to find $(x^4+x^3)*(x^3+x^2+1) \mod x^5+x^2+1$

But I don't know how to reduce the following degree 7 polynomial. Also, I understand we expect our answer f, to have $deg(f) \leq 5$ since we're working in a multiplicative field.

Edit: also these are polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: It should be clear you are *not* multiplying/reducing polynomials, but rather equivalence classes in $\;GF(2^5)\cong\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^5+x^2+1)\;$ ...

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, we are multiplying/reducing polynomials which are representatives of residue classes $\mod x^5+x^2+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to replace each occurrence of $x^5$ with $x^2+1$ (taking into account we're in characteristic $2$):
\begin{align}
(x^4+x^3)(x^3+x^2+1)&=x^7+\color{red}{x^6}+x^4+\color{red}{x^6}+x^5+x^3=x^7+x^5+x^4+x^3\\
&=x^5(x^2+1)+x^4+x^3=(x^2+1)^2+x^4+x^3\\&=\color{red}{x^4}+1+\color{red}{x^4}+x^3=x^3+1.\end{align}

Comment: This is by far the best way to do it, but OP has to be made aware that it amounts to dividing the degree-seven product by $x^5+x^2+1$, and taking the remainder as the desired product.

Comment: I don't understand step four of your calculation. Is $x^5 \equiv x^2+1 \mod x^5+x^2+1$ ? And that's why you can just replace x^5 with that? Why is that and what is your intuition for coming up with this method?

Comment: @Lubin: You're right, but what you describe is the general way to multiply in a quotient ring, in the particular case of a Euclidean domain as  a base ring.

Comment: Yes, and it looked to me as if OP was unaware of it.

Comment: I just did the long division calculation of the degree 7 product: I get a quotient of $x^2 + 1$ and a remainder of $(x^2+1)^2$ I am unsure of what this means

Comment: @Uq'''12wn1F12u2x3uW31H1JBk9m: It's exactly what you describe. Congruence modulo $x^5+x^2+1$ is made to have $x^5+x^2+1=0$, which is the same as $x^5\equiv x^2+1$ (characteristic $2$!). After this observation, just the apply the usual rules for congruences in relation w.r.t. addition and multiplication.

Comment: Oh wow I get it! 
In the future for a general case: If I would like to reduce a polynomial of high degree n, in this same situation Congruence modulo $x^7+x^3+1$ for instance, I would just use $x^7 \equiv x^3 + 1 \mod x^7 + x^3 + 1$ (over characteristic field 2) to reduce it?

Comment: In your division, did you take into account that$a=a$, and $2a=0$? I obtain the same quotient, but my remainder is $x^3+1$.

Comment: As an answer to your last question: yes. It's for the very same reason that $\mathbf C$ can be described as the quotient $\mathbf R[X]/(X^2+1)$.

Comment: Here is a photo of my calculation: http://imgur.com/a/wZbIu

Comment: The dividend is wrong.

Comment: Cool about Complex numbers! The dividend being $x^7+x^5$ ?

Comment: No. You have it at the end of the first line of my calculation: $x^7+x^5+x^4+x^3$.